# Save frequency data of histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, frequency

I have two data set that been read from a txt file.
I plot two histogram as picture below.
How can i get and save the frequency data of this histogram? (i checked at the workspace, but no frequency values)

Note:
X-Axis are values from txt file
Y-Axis are the frequency

[image]

The coding of above histogram plot.

```
clear;
clc;

filename = 'DistanceValue1.txt';
filename1 = 'DistanceValue2.txt';
A = importdata(filename);
B = importdata(filename1);


h1 = histogram (A,50);
hold on
h2 = histogram (B,50);
hold off
```

Answer (score 2):

`histogram` is a Matlab class for plotting data distributions. If you want access to the data use  [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html). Use

```
[n1, edges] = histcounts(A, 50);
[n2, edges] = histcounts(B, 50);
```

Comment: this might be helpful. i am trying to shift using hist instead of histogram. tq!

Comment: i get to access the data especially frequency of the histogram by using histcounts. tq!

Answer (score 0):

The `histogram` object contains its frequency data in the [`Values` property](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram-properties.html), which can be accessed so:

```
h1counts = h1.Values;
```

Comment: already check in the value property, its said that the variable h1.Values does not exist.

Comment: @syakey That is weird, because `histogram` was introduced in 2014b, as well as graphics handles as objects. Sure `h1` exists in your workspace as created by your question's code?

Comment: Sorry I omitted the 's', make sure it's `Values`

Comment: yes, h1 exists in my workspace however when i click on value property in h1 tab menu, as stated, values does not exist. i am using 2015a btw.

Comment: @syakey What happens if you enter `h1.Values` on the command line? I do see the `Values` field in the inspector greyed out, meaning it is read-only.